# Nodejs Archiver ArchiverError: archive already finalizing

Tags: node.js, node-archiver

I want to zip folders excluding certain files/folders so I used the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087344).
The solution works for a single folder but throws error when there are multiple folders to be zipped.

I need to make zips from each sub-folders of the source directory

```
Rootfolder:
 |-folder1
 |-folder2
 |-folder3
```

should result in:

```
build:
 |-{timeFormat}_folder1.zip
 |-{timeFormat}_folder2.zip
 |-{timeFormat}_folder3.zip
```

I am getting following error:

```
".../node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:778
    var finalizingError = new ArchiverError('FINALIZING');
                          ^
ArchiverError: archive already finalizing
...
 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'FINALIZING',
  data: undefined
}"
```

My code is as follows:

```
const zipFolders = async (
  rootPath: string,
  dirPaths: string[]
): Promise<void> => {
  for await (const folder of dirPaths) {
    await makeZip(folder, rootPath);
  }
};
```

.........

```
const fs = require("fs");
const archiver = require("archiver");
const archive = archiver("zip");
import { format } from "date-fns";

const exclude =["assets/**","**/*.json"]

export const makeZip = (srcFolder: string, rootPath: string): Promise<void> =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const timestamp = format(new Date(), "MM-DD-YYYY_HH-mm-ssZZ");
    const dirParts = srcFolder.split("/");
    const dirName = dirParts[dirParts.length - 1];
    const zipName = `${timestamp}_${dirName}`;
    const zipPath = `${rootPath}/build/${zipName}.zip`;


    const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipPath);
    output.on("close", function () {
      console.log("done writing: " + archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
      resolve();
    });
    archive.pipe(output);

    archive.on("error", function (err: Error) {
      throw err;
    });

    archive.glob("**/*", {
      cwd: srcFolder,
      ignore: exclude,
    });

    archive.finalize();
  });
```

I need some help regarding what needs to be updated or if there is any other way of achieving the same thing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution I ended up using.

```
const exclude = ["assets/**", "**/*.json"];

const makeZip = (srcFolder: string, rootPath: string): Promise<void> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timestamp = format(new Date(), "MM-DD-YYYY_HH-mm-ssZZ");
    const dirParts = srcFolder.split("/");
    const dirName = dirParts[dirParts.length - 1];
    const zipName = `${timestamp}_${dirName}`;
    const zipPath = `${rootPath}/build/${zipName}.zip`;

    const archive = archiver("zip");
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipPath);

    output.on("close", function () {
      console.log("done writing: " + archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
      resolve();
    });

    archive.on("error", function (err: Error) {
      reject(err);
    });

    archive.glob("**/*", {
      cwd: srcFolder,
      ignore: exclude,
    });

    archive.pipe(output);
    archive.finalize();
  });
```

......

```
const zipFolders = async (rootPath: string, dirPaths: string[]): Promise<void> => {
  const promises = dirPaths.map((folder) => makeZip(folder, rootPath));
  await Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the finalize() method call outside of the makeZip function and call it only once after all the folders have been added to the archive. Here's an updated version of your zipFolders function that should work:

```
const zipFolders = async (
  rootPath: string,
  dirPaths: string[]
): Promise<void> => {
  const archive = archiver('zip');
  const output = fs.createWriteStream(`${rootPath}/build/archive.zip`);
  output.on("close", function () {
    console.log("done writing: " + archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
  });
  archive.pipe(output);

  for await (const folder of dirPaths) {
    const timestamp = format(new Date(), "MM-DD-YYYY_HH-mm-ssZZ");
    const dirParts = folder.split("/");
    const dirName = dirParts[dirParts.length - 1];
    const zipName = `${timestamp}_${dirName}`;
    const zipPath = `${rootPath}/build/${zipName}.zip`;

    await makeZip(archive, folder, zipPath);
  }

  archive.finalize();
};

export const makeZip = (
  archive: archiver.Archiver,
  srcFolder: string,
  zipPath: string
): Promise<void> =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    const exclude =["assets/**","**/*.json"]

    const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipPath);
    output.on("close", function () {
      console.log("done writing: " + archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
      resolve();
    });
    archive.pipe(output);

    archive.on("error", function (err: Error) {
      throw err;
    });

    archive.glob("**/*", {
      cwd: srcFolder,
      ignore: exclude,
    });
  });
```

---

**Answer to other question:**

If you want to create separate zip files for each subfolder, you can modify the zipFolders function to create a new archive instance for each subfolder, like this:

```
const zipFolders = async (rootPath: string, dirPaths: string[]): Promise<void> => {
  for await (const folder of dirPaths) {
    const timestamp = format(new Date(), "MM-DD-YYYY_HH-mm-ssZZ");
    const dirParts = folder.split("/");
    const dirName = dirParts[dirParts.length - 1];
    const zipName = `${timestamp}_${dirName}`;
    const zipPath = `${rootPath}/build/${zipName}.zip`;

    const archive = archiver("zip");
    const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipPath);

    output.on("close", function () {
      console.log("done writing: " + archive.pointer() + " total bytes");
    });

    archive.on("error", function (err: Error) {
      throw err;
    });

    archive.glob("**/*", {
      cwd: folder,
      ignore: exclude,
    });

    archive.pipe(output);
    archive.finalize();
  }
};
```

Comment: `createWriteStream` and `archive.pipe(output)` should only be called once as well, to avoid creating multiple write streams and doing additional unnecessary work.

Comment: @Koray Thank you for the swift reply. I have updated my question about how I need zip from each subfolders. I tried your solution and it did try to make a new archive.zip but it was unable to expand.