# How would I go about testing a package such as node-archiver with Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I found the following [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62405527/10824322) for zipping a directory using [node-archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) (I've modified it a bit):

```js
function zipDirectory(source, dest) {
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    archive
      .directory(source, false)
      .on("error", (err) => reject(err))
      .pipe(stream);
 
    stream.on("close", () => resolve());
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

I want to test it with Jest, however I haven't been able to even mock the package.

Comment: have u ever thought of getting ideas from the test folder in node-archiver?